# How to check if user with [UserName] and [Password] is domain administrator of [DomainName] without impersonation?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

[Impersonation example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joncole/archive/2009/09/21/impersonation-code-in-c.aspx)

I can check is user domain administrator with next lines of code:

```
using (Impersonation im = new Impersonation(UserName, Domain, Password))
{
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    bool isDomainAdmin = identity.IsDomainAdmin(Domain, UserName, Password);
    if (!isDomainAdmin)
    {
        //deny access, for example
    }
}
```

where IsDomainAdmin - is extension method

```
public static bool IsDomainAdmin(this WindowsIdentity identity, string domain, string userName, string password)
{
    Domain d = Domain.GetDomain(new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, domain, userName, password));

    using (DirectoryEntry de = d.GetDirectoryEntry())
    {
        byte[] domainSIdArray = (byte[])de.Properties["objectSid"].Value;
        SecurityIdentifier domainSId = new SecurityIdentifier(domainSIdArray, 0);
        SecurityIdentifier domainAdminsSId = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AccountDomainAdminsSid, domainSId);
        WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return wp.IsInRole(domainAdminsSId);
    }
}
```

But, when method IsDomainAdmin is called, it is trying to write some files to the %LOCALAPPDATA% for impersonated user, and if program is runnig not as administrator, it throws an exception

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.DirectoryServices,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not
>   provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80070542)

Comment: Useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160262/how-can-i-determine-if-a-windows-identity-corresponds-to-a-local-or-a-domain-use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly don't need a user's password to verify if the user is a member of a group. So why don't you just query AD in a straight-forward manner using `DirectoryEntry` or `DirectorySearcher`? If you also need to verify that the password supplied is correct you can do that in an additional step using `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials`. (See [PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb154889.aspx)).

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string userDomain = "somedomain";
    string userName = "username";
    string password = "apassword";

    if (IsDomainAdmin(userDomain, userName)) {
        string fullUserName = userDomain + @"\" + userName;
        PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(
            ContextType.Domain, userDomain);
        if (context.ValidateCredentials(fullUserName, password)) {
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        }
    }
}

public static bool IsDomainAdmin(string domain, string userName) {
    string adminDn = GetAdminDn(domain);
    SearchResult result = (new DirectorySearcher(
        new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain),
        "(&(objectCategory=user)(samAccountName=" + userName + "))",
        new[] { "memberOf" })).FindOne();
    return result.Properties["memberOf"].Contains(adminDn);
}

public static string GetAdminDn(string domain) {
    return (string)(new DirectorySearcher(
        new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain),
        "(&(objectCategory=group)(cn=Domain Admins))")
        .FindOne().Properties["distinguishedname"][0]);
}
```

Comment: first part is right - I need to verify user credentials. I don't know enough about LDAP queries, but if I change `"cn=Domain Admins"` to `"cn=Domain Users"`, I will always get false but I know that the user with provided name exist. May be there are some mistakes at the queries?

Comment: AD users aren't explicitly added to the group `Domain Users`; it's implied. So the dn for the Domain Users group will not be in the memberOf list. Try searching for your user and enumerating the items in `memberOf` to understand better.

Comment: Its works! BUT! I don't like solution with hardcoded string `"Domain Admins"`. Can group of domain admins have another name in some AD structure?

Answer (score 2):

We are modified @jmh_gr answer, and it seems to become independent from `"Domain Admins"` group name.

```
static string BuildOctetString(SecurityIdentifier sid)
{
    byte[] items = new byte[sid.BinaryLength];
    sid.GetBinaryForm(items, 0);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in items)
    {
        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
public static bool IsDomainAdmin(string domain, string userName)
{
    using (DirectoryEntry domainEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}", domain)))
    {
        byte[] domainSIdArray = (byte[])domainEntry.Properties["objectSid"].Value;

        SecurityIdentifier domainSId = new SecurityIdentifier(domainSIdArray, 0);
        SecurityIdentifier domainAdminsSId = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AccountDomainAdminsSid, domainSId);

        using (DirectoryEntry groupEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://<SID={0}>", BuildOctetString(domainAdminsSId))))
        {
            string adminDn = groupEntry.Properties["distinguishedname"].Value as string;
            SearchResult result = (new DirectorySearcher(domainEntry, string.Format("(&(objectCategory=user)(samAccountName={0}))", userName), new[] { "memberOf" })).FindOne();
            return result.Properties["memberOf"].Contains(adminDn);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, thanks to @jmh_gr for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code by @lluisfranco

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Alpha.Code
{
    public static class SecurityExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsDomainAdmin (this WindowsIdentity identity)
        {
            Domain d = Domain.GetDomain(new
                DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, getDomainName()));
            using (DirectoryEntry de = d.GetDirectoryEntry())
            {
                byte[] bdomSid = (byte[])de.Properties["objectSid"].Value;
                string sdomainSid = sIDtoString(bdomSid);
                WindowsPrincipal wp = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
                SecurityIdentifier dsid = new SecurityIdentifier(sdomainSid);
                SecurityIdentifier dasid = new SecurityIdentifier(
                    WellKnownSidType.AccountDomainAdminsSid, dsid);
                return wp.IsInRole(dasid);
            }
        }

        public static string getDomainName()
        {
            return IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
        }

        public static string sIDtoString(byte[] sidBinary)
        {
            SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(sidBinary, 0);
            return sid.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
if (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsDomainAdmin())
{
    //Actions to do if user is domain admin
}
```

Source:
http://geeks.ms/blogs/lfranco/archive/2009/11/25/how-to-191-como-saber-si-el-usuario-actual-es-administrador-del-dominio.aspx

Comment: this is the same solution as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @stukselbax Which final solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9684475/206730 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/9698448/206730 ?

Comment: We have used the last one, because it name-independent, but the main idea was originated from the first answer. Both answers are valid.